# Does mustache have ABNF defined grammar?

Tags: mustache

I want to make custom mustache grammar parser. 
I would like to use existent  grammar definition of it.
But, I could not find one. 
Is it exists? Where can I find one. 
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I started to write one, once, but things like delimiter changing and standalone tags make it less trivial than I'd initially thought.

While it's not a grammar, I'm assuming you know about the mustache spec?

https://github.com/mustache/spec